# Regular functions on a closed set under the Zariski Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm having a tough time understanding regular functions on a closed set under the Zariski topology. 
Are these any rational functions that do not blow up at any point on $X$?

For instance, if I were to compute the set of regular functions on $\Bbb{A}^1\setminus \{0\}$, would these be $k(x)$, where $x$ is invertible?

The definition of a regular function on a closed set given in class was that at all points on the variety (or maybe just open subsets of the variety), it takes the same values as a globally defined polynomial. But maybe I'm remembering it wrong.

Comment: Yes, but $A^1 \backslash \{0\}$ is not closed in $A^1$ ... For an open set, it is all the rational function $f/g$ where $g \neq 0$ on $U$. For closed subset, it is the ring $k[X]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal of the closed set.

Comment: Sorry, I said yes but of course it's no : for example, $\frac{1}{x-1} \in k(x)$ but it's not a regular function on $A^1 \backslash \{0\}$. The regular function on $A^1 \backslash \{0\}$ is $k[x,x^{-1}]$.